# How to check if keyboard is visible?

Tags: flutter, dart

How to check if the keyboard is visible or not in Flutter?

I want to show/hide a widget on the keyboard's visibility state.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[keyboard_visibility](https://pub.dev/packages/keyboard_visibility) this package will helps you in detecting the visibility of virtual keyboard in both ios and android.

```
import 'package:keyboard_visibility/keyboard_visibility.dart';

@protected
void initState() {
  super.initState();

  KeyboardVisibilityNotification().addNewListener(
    onChange: (bool visible) {
      print(visible);
    },
  );
}
```